# Quick find in Nautilus is broken

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

This is a bit difficult to explain, so I'll present it as 'What I do'/'What should happen'/'What happens'.

What I do:

I open a directory and I want to find a file/folder by typing the first letters of its name - its a feature I use a lot. Then I hit Alt+Backspace.

[image]

What should happen:

The last character in the quick find box should be deleted.

What happens:

I go up one directory. It's as if the letter box doesn't hold the keyboard focus.

Does that happen for other people, and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been bugging me since upgrading to 11.10. Today I decided to try and replace nautilus with elementary, which I have done before on 11.04. Elementary has been replaced by Marlin. So I installed marlin, which is its own file manager (not a replacement). Marlin seemed to not have this issue. By accident I opened up nautilus again and noticed that the problem had gone away. I wonder if this is a coincidence or marlin updated something that fixed it?

anyway i followed the guide on [Marlin (elementary File Browser) Gets Dropbox And UbuntuOne Plugins](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/marlin-elementary-file-browser-gets.html)
and ran the following:
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install marlin marlin-plugin-dropbox marlin-plugin-ubuntuone

Comment: The latest update from Ubuntu fixed it. When I saw nautilus as part of the updates I immediately checked what the update was about, and the summary said that problems with focus in quicktype are fixed. Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a fine bug report, but this is not the place for that. This site is for questions and answers, like "How do I". Bugs are filed on http://launchpad.net and reports are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if someone has found a workaround, and if it happens for other people too.

Comment: It's better to fix the problem than to keep having to work around them.